# How to describe following situation?

Tags: sentence-construction

I and my friend came out from our class and were going to powder our noses. After reaching near to bathrooms, we found that doors of all bathrooms were closed, meaning that some students had already entered the bathrooms. My friend asked to me to describe this situation in English language. 'All bathrooms are packed', I said to him, adding that you might also say all toilets are being used.
Was I right in describing the above mentioned situation? How will a native English speaker describe this situation?

Comment: All stalls were occupied.

Comment: What @ЯegDwight said. The legend on bathroom door locks often shows either ***vacant*** or ***occupied***. We also often see the word ***engaged*** in this context, but I tend to see that as a reference to the lock itself (where the internal bolt mechanism is "engaged / locked", meaning the door can't be opened). But ***occupied*** clearly refers to the cubicle, not the lock.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say _engaged_ on a lock is used in its [_busy/occupied_ sense](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+engaged&oq=define+engaged&aqs=chrome..69i57.2352j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Similar to a 'phone _being engaged_.

Comment: "All the toilets are being used" is fine. Also: All the toilets are occupied. Also the first suggestion. in AmE, we say stalls, but toilet is ok, too.

Comment: I would say *The bathroom is full.* (Which is more idiomatic than literal.)

Comment: [How to describe **the** following situation.]

Answer (score 1):

> All the (toilets/cubicles/stalls) were (busy/engaged/occupied/being used).

There are a few dialect differences. Using "stall" is American, as is "bathroom" (when referring to a place without a bath).

You could also use a negative statement "None of the toilets were (free/available/vacant)"